# KnockoutJs: Get the bound element from a model instance

Tags: knockout.js

Is it at all possible to get the corresponding element (or elements) that a data (model) instance was bound to?

For example, I have an array of 'Person' objects stores in a ViewModel property.

I bind the ViewModel to the view which renders it, eg:

```
<div class="people" data-bind="template: { foreach: people }">
    <a href="#" class="person" data-bind="text: name"></a>
</div>
```

I then bind some event handlers via jQuery:

```javascript
$container.on('click', '.person', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    self.showPerson( ko.dataFor(this) );
});
```

In my `showPerson` method I would save a reference to the model. I /could/ also a save a reference to the element, but I don't want to if I don't have to.

```javascript
self.showPerson = function(person) {
    // can i get the corresponding element from the 'person' model?
};
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your syntax and use of $container with jquery and the second argument of '.person' is unfamiliar to me, but in your click handler, isn't `this` the element that was clicked?  Couldn't you pass that to your showPerson method also?

```
$container.on('click', '.person', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    self.showPerson( ko.dataFor(this), this );
});

self.showPerson = function(person, element) {
    // can i get the corresponding element from the 'person' model?
};
```

I don't know of a way off the top of my head to get the elements that an observable is bound to, but it could be several different elements.  You could have a text box for 'name', display the name in a span, use it in a computed, have subscribers, and use name().length in a calculation in another binding for instance.

That said, if you use the debug version of knockout, you can see that your observables have a `_subscriptions` property that might have what you're looking for.  The minified version is some single character I think.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Of-course the easiest way to do this is to save a reference to the element, but in my question I've mentioned I don't want to do this if I don't have to. But I think your answer has confirmed that it is not possible to get a list of elements the observable was bound to, which i feel is lacking API method method of knockoutjs.

Answer (score 22):

You can simply create a custom binding

```
    // data-bind="element: observable"
    // sets observable to element ..
    ko.bindingHandlers.element = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            var target = valueAccessor();
            target(element);
        }
    };
```

In your view model, create a 'field' to store the element:

```
person.el = ko.observable(null);
```

Then in your html template ..

```
<div data-bind="element: el"> .... </div>
```

Comment: This should have been the answer, because that is the only solution on the page that lets me simply get access to the bound element from inside view model, not when clicked, but as soon as it is bound.

Comment: This made it so easy, and lets you create multiple observables to hold references to multiple HTML objects within the model.  What a great solution!

Answer (score 5):

Why not move the click event binding inside your `foreach`?

`<a href="#" class="person" data-bind="text: name, click: showPerson"></a>`

In this case, your `showPerson()` function would have the correct data for `person`

EDIT :

Sorry, but I guess I missed the core of your question:

```
self.showPerson = function (person, event) {
     element = event.srcElement
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I'm asking. `showPerson()` gets the correct data. I'm asking if I can get the corresponding element from the Model instance that is passed into `showPerson()`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.showPerson = function(data, event) {
  // event.currentTarget is the DOM element
  // $(event.currentTarget) gives the jQuery element
}
```

Comment: I was asking if I could get the element from the model, not from the event handler parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think best practice is to bind directly to a function on the view model rather than attach handlers.

[Click binding to parent function in foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804705/knockout-js-click-binding-to-parent-function-in-foreach)